# How to use factor theorem for a polynomial with three binomial factors, i.e. (a+b)(b+c)(a+c)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I am working on a proof and I am completely baffled on how to use factor theorem for more than one binomial factors (as divisors). I find that showing the LHS is equivalent to the RHS is more difficult than showing the RHS is equivalent to the LHS.

$3a^2b+3a^2c+ 3b^2a+3b^2c+3c^2a+3c^2b+6abc=3(a+b)(a+b)(a+c)$

I figured out that the common factor would be $3$ using polynomial division. So that  and taking out the common factor of the right hand side leaves us with

$3[a^2b+a^2c+b^2a+b^2c+c^2a+c^2b+2abc]$

I used polynomial division from there  on to show that (a+b)(b+c)(a+c) and $a^2b+a^2c+b^2a+b^2c+c^2a+c^2b+2abc$ are equivalent. If someone could show me the steps (that could be understood by someone with some experience with polynomials) that would be very much obliged!

Comment: Is there a specific reason you’re avoiding simply multiplying out $3(a+b)(b+c)(a+c)$?

Comment: It's easier to multiply than to factor.

Comment: You do it in a similar way. Let $f(a, b, c) = 3a^2b + 3a^2c + \ldots + 6abc$. If we are (somehow) able to determine that $ f(-b, b, c) = 0$, which then implies that $(a+b) \mid f(a, b, c)$.  $\quad$ As another example, consider $g(a, b, c) = a^3 + b^3 + c^3 - 3abc$. Show that $g(-b-c, b, c ) = 0 $ and hence $(a+b+c) \mid g(a, b, c)$. $\quad$ You could also have constants in there, like if $ h(-b-2c+1, b, c) = 0 $, then $a+b+2c-1 \mid h(a, b, c)$.

Comment: @William I am trying to get the left hand side to the right hand side. It's easy to multiply (a+b)(b+c)(a+c) but I am having difficulty showing the left hand side is equivalent. Idk if that makes sense.